# How do I to select and copy different parts of excel to excel in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a beginner with an excel database and I want to be able to click a button and generate a csv from it so it can be in a format that can be fed into another SQL database (and also people will stop manually copying and pasting from it!).

The code I have - made with help from other forums- allows the bulk data to be copied over and a header to be generated.

```
Sub Button3_Click()



Dim srminsampls_test_csv As String
Dim Minsamps As Workbook
Dim CSV As Workbook
Dim copyRng As Range
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error GoTo err

Set Minsamps = ThisWorkbook
srminsampls_test_csv = Minsamps.Path & "\" & "CSV-Exported-File-" & VBA.Format(VBA.Now, "dd-MMM-yyyy hh-mm") & ".csv"


'to select and copy the assay data:'
    Set rng1 = Cells.Find("", [C4], xlFormulas, xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    Set rng2 = Cells.Find("", [F4], xlFormulas, xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        Set copyRng = Range([C4], Cells(rng1.Row, rng2.Column))
    Else
        MsgBox "sheet is blank", vbCritical
    End If

   copyRng.Copy

'create the new sheet
    Set CSV = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
    With CSV
        .Sheets(1).Range("A12").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'insert the csv header
        .Sheets(1).Range("A1").Select
        .Sheets(1).Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "Report_No"
        .Sheets(1).Range("A2").Select
        .Sheets(1).Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "No_Samples"
        .Sheets(1).Range("A3").Select
        .Sheets(1).Range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "DATE_RECEIVED"
'etc etc...there are many many lines of similar code here!

'save and generate file
        .SaveAs Filename:=myCSVFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        .Close
    End With

err:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub`
```

It allows the header to show DATE_RECEIVED, but I don't know how to copy over a value from the original sheet (Minsamps) and paste it into the cell next to DATE_RECEIVED. Whatever I do either stops the header and other copy/paste code from working or the whole sheet comes out blank.  Sorry if this is very simple but I just can't seem to work it out.
Thanks,
EJ

Comment: Change line `.Sheets(1).Range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "DATE_RECEIVED"` to `.Sheets(1).Range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "DATE_RECEIVED:  "& Now()` . It should work. Add some space after "DATE RECEIVED" within quotes to maintain some space. As i Understand it you want to show time file is created.

Comment: If you want to format time to restrict up-to minutes only the make it `.Sheets(1).Range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "DATE_RECEIVED: "& Format(Now(), "dd-MMM-yyyy hh-mm")`

Comment: Thanks skkakkar, but the DATE RECEIVED is the date the lab receives the data, not necessarily the date the report is generated. This date comes from the original excel sheet (Minsamps). I'm not sure how to copy this date over.

Comment: Could you upload the sample portion of file corrupting confidential information to some reputed site like drop box, onedrive etc

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7u74cxc2vq9x90a/minsampls_test2.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: Your file was uploaded 8 hours ago but it was midnight here. I have assumed your dates in report are in consistent pattern. I have taken date variable value from `Range("A4")`. I have commented changes made by me.It now shows the date from original sheet. Only this part of your code has been looked into . Modified file link is <https://www.dropbox.com/s/o0jotqlkfiqp97l/minsampls_test2.xlsm?dl=0>

Comment: Sorry, I'm in Australia. Thank you, works perfectly!

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. I am posting my answer and please take some time out of your busy schedule to mark my answer as accepted. To mark an answer as accepted, Please click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following changes / additions shall enable desired program execution.

In declarations please add following lines.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet 'Added worksheet variable
Dim dtrep As String  'Added date string variable
```

set value of date variable to original sheet `Range("A4")` value

```
    Set ws = Minsamps.Worksheets(1)
    dtrep = ws.Range("A4").Value     'set value of date variable to original sheet "A4"
```

Change following line

```
.Sheets(1).Range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "DATE_RECEIVED"
```

To

```
.Sheets(1).Range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "DATE_RECEIVED" & " - " & dtrep
```

Rest seems to be okay. 
HTH